# Hide wordpress side menu at home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I,m new to word press installed and live site [guestpostservice.org][1]

[1]: http://guestpostservice.org , i'm trying to hide default theme side menu but not able to do that, someone please help me what should i do, need Home,Contact,Blog etc in main menu.

Comment: Where you want your menu?

Comment: Menu at header, but default theme is showing it at side menu. I want to create it custom.

Answer (score 0):

Open "sidebar.php" in your Twenty Fifteen theme directory and just comment or remove "wp_nav_menu" function.

So your code will look like (I've just added "`/*`" and "`*/`"):

```
<?php /* if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
                <?php
                    // Primary navigation menu.
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'menu_class'     => 'nav-menu',
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                    ) );
                ?>
            </nav><!-- .main-navigation -->
        <?php endif; */ ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help

Comment: @user7199225 no worries, please accept it as answer if it helps ;)